# Copy only visible cells

Tags: excel, vba, visibility, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy visible cells after using my filter to another sheet in the same book but I'm not sure about this code. How it looks like now:

```
     Sub Button1_Click()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim VisRan As Range
        VisRan = Sheets(1).Range("a39:bm29684").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Visran.Copy   
        Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Select
        Selection.Paste
```

But it doesn't work. What's the problem?
Thx in advance

Comment: You have no **With** and you have no **Copy**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent sry I accidentally have deleted this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim VisRan As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisRan = Sheets(1).Range("a39:bm29684").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If VisRan Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no visible rows"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    VisRan.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```